# How do you change the javafx text style for a menubar?

Tags: javafx

So I have a menubar in javafx and how do you change the text style of the menu and menu items font and color. I'm new to javafx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so create a css file for the application
then for a example inside you will have

```css
.menu .label {
    -fx-font-family: what ever the font style you want then put a semicolon at then end.
    -fx-fill: color name you want and put a semicolon at then end.
}
```

then apply the stylesheet to the main frame
`stylesheets="@application.css"`
in you fxml file
then you should be good to go.